# Change which anchor is displayed depending on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

When user clicks 'Show Product' a list of links display, when the user clicks 'Show product' again the list of links disappear. This works fine, however when the list is displayed I want to change the text to 'Hide Product'

So far I can get everything working (with thanks to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) but I have not been able to change the text to 'hide product' please advise where I can find out how to do this?

Thank ye

```
  <li id="showProductCategories" class="showProductCategories">
           <a>Show Product</a>
        </li>

        //<li id="hideProductCategories" class="showProductCategories">
           //<a>Hide Product</a>
        //</li>

     <div id="productLink">
          <ul class="categorymenu">
             @foreach (ProductCategoryRecord pc in Model.ProductCategories)
             {
                 <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Store", new { id = pc.Name })">@pc.Name</a></li>
             }

             @if (Model.ProductCategories.Count() <= 0)
             {
                  <p>There are no products in this category</p>
             }
          </ul>
     </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $('#showProductCategories').click(function () {
             $('#productLink').toggle('slow', function () {

                 //something in here about hideProductCategories??

             });
         });
     </Script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#showProductCategories').click(function () {    
    $('#productLink').toggle('slow');
    var anchor = $(this).find("a");
    anchor.text(anchor.text() == "Show Product" ? "Hide Product" : "Show Product");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$('#showProductCategories').click(function () { 
    var anchor = $(this).find("a");   
    $('#productLink').toggle('slow', function () {
        anchor.text($(this).is(":visible") ? "Hide Product" : "Show Product");
    });        
});
```